# MatDialog is not opening on Safari iOS 10

Tags: ios, angular, mobile-safari, angular-material2

I have a problem with opening dialogs on **Safari iOS 10.3.3** (Angular 5.2, Angular Material 5.2.4). I can open and close dialog multiple times but after several attempts dialog doesn't show up (dialog is visible in the **DOM** but is not shown to the user). When I trigger any style recalculation in dev tools dialog shows up. Switching browser tab and switching it back also helps.

My problem is related to issue https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10530.

Do you have any workaround or idea how can fix it before Angular Material team will solve this?